# Integration in Python from a custom module/.py file

Tags: python

I have an integration.py file containing the following script:

```
def trapezoidal(f, a, b, n=100):
    h = (b-a)/n
    f_sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n, 1):
        x = a + i*h
        f_sum = f_sum + f(x)
    return h*(0.5*f(a) + f_sum + 0.5*f(b))
```

After importing the integration module, I have to use the trapezoidal rule to find the integral.
The only problem I am facing is how to write/feed the function to be integrated.

I have the following function to be integrated:

integral from 0 to 1  of  (7 + 14 x^6)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I edited your question to keep it focused. SO is meant to be like a reference, so we keep "fluff" like "hi" and "thanks" out of posts here. As well, you can't really ask not to be downvoted; if you ask a bad question, you'll get downvotes (not to say this is a bad question necessarily). To make sure you ask good questions, check out [ask].

Comment: Beside the point, but you can simplify `f_sum = f_sum + f(x)` as `f_sum += f(x)`, or better yet, the whole loop as `f_sum = sum(a + i*h for i in range(1, n, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the function and insert it to `f`

```py
# By defining function
def target_func(x):
    return 7 + 14 * x ** 6
result1 = trapezoidal(target_func, 0, 1)

# Using lambda function
result2 = trapezoidal(lambda x:7 + 14 * x **6, 0, 1)
```

Comment: I have to import the module like this

import integration as integ

def target_func(x):
    return 7 + 14 * x ** 6
result1 = integ.trapezoidal(target_func, 0, 1)


following error shows up : module 'integration' has no attribute 'trapezoidal'

Comment: Does `from integration import trapezoidal` give an error?

Comment: @AmirHamza There seems nothing wrong on your approach. Have you tried `from integration import trapzoidal`?

Comment: @AmirHamza That's a separate issue. You might have forgotten to save `integration.py`. Or your setup might be importing the wrong `integration` module; run `print(integration)` to check the file path.

Comment: @NoThlnG Typo: `trapzoidal` -> `trapezoidal`

Comment: .py is saved. path is okay too. Still the error showing up :((

Comment: I also tried from integration import trapezoidal. The function also showed in the suggestions but at the end of the day the same error shows up

Comment: Which version of python do you use? Do you have `__init__.py` in the directory?

Comment: Also any chance of importing wrong `integration.py`? Like you have module of same name in one of your `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Try `import integration` and `print(integration)` to see if module is imported from the correct directory.

Comment: oh i see it is importing from a wrong directory. i deleted the duplicated file. what to do now?

Comment: What's the result? I don't see the reason for the code to not work if it imports correctly

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. Everything worked fine. First, python was importing the wrong .py file. I deleted the old one and rebooted my system. Thanks once again. God bless